# Does the term 'Powers of 10' include zero and negative powers?

Tags: terminology, exponentiation

When the term 'powers of 10' is used in a sentence, does it include *zero* and/or *negative* powers of 10?

That is, does the term 'powers of 10' mean these

`10 100 1000 10000 ...`

or these

`... 0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.1 1 10 100 1000 ...`

or these

`1 10 100 1000 10000 ...`

or is it ambiguous/dependent on context?

Note: I want to use it in a sentence and I *do* wish to include zero and negative powers of ten, so I want to know if I need to specifically mention that, or if simply 'Powers of 10' is sufficient.

Comment: It probably depends to who you are talking to. The common mortal would think $10, 100...$ and a mathematician (guessing, since I'm not) would probably accept $1, 10^{-7}$...

Comment: Not just mathematicians. A scientist is used to writing values like $5.3\times10^{-6}$. But I agree that few non-mathematicians would refer to 1 as a power of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a discrete context, such as combinatorics where such powers may arise in the solutions of recurrence relations, the powers of ten usually start from $10^0=1$. The set including negative powers would be said as "numbers of the form $10^k$ where $k$ is an integer" or similar.

In a continuous context, such as numerical analysis (how many steps of an algorithm must be performed to get below a desired error, how many correct digits does each step add, etc.), powers of ten are infinite on both ends, so $10^{-7}$ is a power of ten. This is also standard usage in the other sciences and famously in the Eames film *Powers of Ten*.